# Java Method Best Design Practice

Tags: java, methods

I know in Java a method is created whenever a block of code is going to be executed many times.

For example printPlusOne below will be called five times:

```
    class Count{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                printPlusOne(i);
            }
        }

       public static void printPlusOne(int i){
            int sum  = i + 1;
            System.out.println(sum);
       }
    }
```

But what if I want to execute a block of related code only once. Should I also create a method for it? Or should I just leave code in the main method like below.
In general, is it a good design practice to create methods even if they will be called only once? Or are these just unnecessary and I can leave the block of code in the main method?

```
     class Count{

         public static void main(String[] args) {

             //The below will print only once at the beginning of the program.
             //Should I create a method for it even if it runs only once?

             System.out.println("This is the introduction.");
             System.out.println("The program will return a count");
             System.out.println("Have fun.")
         }
     }
```

Comment: The number of times code is called is irrelevant.  You would create a method when you have a set of one or more operations which can be encapsulated within a single intuitive and descriptive name for that overall operations.  That is, if you have one or more lines of code to "do a thing" then you would put them into a method which is named for that thing.

Comment: A note about your first example: I would put the whole loop in a method like: `printNums(int start, int end);` it'd be more flexible that way. I would also take care when deciding to bind a method to a particular output stream as it makes the code less flexible.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thanks. I was just using this as a quick example.

Comment: I figured. I thought it might be useful to your question as well. The `printPlusOne` method makes use of an unnecessary `sum` since `i`'s passed by value and really only does one useful thing (printing). So, combining the two into `printNumsPlusOne()` which just does `System.out.println(i + 1)` seems like a better use of a method IMHO.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I tried to create a method with more than one line of code, otherwise the method would be unnecessary. It was just code to lead to my main question.

Comment: @pseudorandom Methods with one line of code are necessary whenever the intention of that line of code is not obvious. Well the criteria is not necessarily the length, although longer methods tends to be verbose and vague on intention.

Answer (score 4):

There are not only "rules of thumb" to guide you here. The whole "[clean code movement](https://gist.github.com/wojteklu/73c6914cc446146b8b533c0988cf8d29)" (somehow based on the excellent absolute must-read "Clean Code" by Robert Martin; go get the free PDF **now**) and its principles are telling us: "the more methods the better".

Or to be more precise:

1. There is the "Single responsibility" principle - that says that any "thingy" in programming (module, class, method) should have a "single responsibility" only. So, a method does "one thing", and one thing only.
2. There is the "Single layer of abstraction" principle; basically telling you that you have not more than **one** if, or **one** loop, or **one** try-catch in your methods.

But to avoid misunderstandings here: the goal is to create code that is "maximum" readable. You don't create many methods because the principles say so. You create those methods that you need to get your job done; not less; but also not more, too!

Finally: the one important aspect of "many short methods are better than few lengthy ones" is: such a setup helps "your brain" to grasp content more quickly. The point is that your brain always tries to find context, "boundaries" when studying anything written down. And it is pretty simple: if you write code that has explicit, easy-to-grasp boundaries; then you are helping your brain when you come back later on and study code. But if you too many things into one method, your brain will start to "slice" the content of method into smaller parts. In other words: you waste brain CPU cycles by forcing your brain to "ignore" the fact that there many small methods hidden in that one large method.

And for the record: don't worry about runtime efficiency. The JVM/JIT is really good at optimizing small methods; the smaller, the easier it might be to *inline* them at runtime.

Comment: Your "clean code movement" link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

My rule of thumb: a method should do one thing and do it well.  If it is only called once today, it may be called elsewhere in six months.  Not only that, as @holtc said, it makes it a lot easier to understand what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Creating methods will make the code more readable/maintainable, but if it will only be called once, it's pretty much up to you, but I would guess that technically it would be best to create a method to make it easier to change/update going forward